# Tri-State gates in CMOS

Tags: tri-state

How do you build tri-state gates on transistor level? I've tried to come up with some designs -like connecting the output of the gate to the source port of a PMOS transistor with the enabled signal as its gate(base)- but it does not actually correspond to CMOS logic. How can I have a tri-state gate in CMOS tech?